# Jboss EAP 6.2 startup error on adding <tx:annotation-driven/>

Tags: mybatis, spring-3, jboss-eap-6

We are using below technology stack:

JbossEAP 6.2 + Spring 3.2.4 + RestEasy 2.3.7 + MyBatis 3.1.1 + MyBatis-Spring 1.2.0.

We are planning to use declarativie transaction and after adding   in applicationContext.xml file we are getting below error:

Please let us me know how to fix it.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'transactionManagerBeanName' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Bean property 'transactionManagerBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 25 more

Note:

We are using below listeners:
    
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    
    
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener

Comment: do we need to update  jboss-deployment-structure.xml to include/exclude any libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I had included spring-dao by mistake, removed it and works fine!